# Borel measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a Borel measurable function and let $h:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $h(x,y)=f(x)+f(y)$. Prove that $h$ is Borel measurable

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1**:

> **Proposition 1:** Let $(E,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space and let $f:(E,\mathcal{A})\to (F_1,\mathcal{B}_1)$, $g:(E,\mathcal{A})\to(F_2,\mathcal{B}_2)$ be two measurable functions. Then the product function
>   \begin{align*}h:(E,\mathcal{A})&\to(F_1\times F_2,\mathcal{B}_1\otimes\mathcal{B}_2)\\x&\mapsto(f(x),g(x))\end{align*}
>   is measurable.

Where $\mathcal{B}_1\otimes\mathcal{B}_2$ denotes the product sigma algebra on $F_1\times F_2$.

*Proof*

We need to show that the preimage of a measurable set with respect to $h$ is measurable. Let us take an arbitrary set
$$\mathcal{C}=\{B_1\times B_2 ; B_1 \in \mathcal{B}_1 , B_2 \in \mathcal{B}_2\}$$

Then we have

$$h^{-1}(B_1\times B_2) = f^{-1}(B_1) \cap g^{-1}(B_2)$$

but $f^{-1}(B_1)$ is measurable since $f$ is measurable and similarly $g^{-1}(B_2)$ is measurable since $g$ is. The intersection of two measurable sets is again measurable, hence $h^{-1}(B_1\times B_2) = f^{-1}(B_1) \cap g^{-1}(B_2)$ is measurable.

**Hint 2**

> **Proposition 2:** The composition of two measurable functions is measurable

*Proof*

Let $f$ and $g$ be two measurable functions then we have

$$ (g \circ f)^{-1}(C) = \underbrace{f^{-1}(\underbrace{g^{-1}(C))}_{\text{measurable}}}_{\text{measurable}}$$

Do you see how to procede?

Comment: How h is a composition of two functions?

Comment: @Zeinab $h$ is not a composition of two functions. But you can compose $h$ with another function to get the sum of two functions and then you use the fact that the composition of two measurable functions is measurable to show that the sum of two measurable  functions is measurable. Do you see which function you need to compose $h$ with?

Comment: @Zeinab Did you get it? Which function did you compose $h$ with?

Comment: Ok.I should think about it.Now I do not know it

Comment: @Zeinab if you need help just ask :)

Comment: Are projective functions useful?I mean p_1(x,y)=x and p_2(x,y)=y.then h(x,y)=go(fop_1,fop_2) that g(x,y)=x+y.

Comment: @Zeinab Yes! You are almost there. What you want is $f(x) + g(x)$ to be measurable, not $x+y$. Do you see the point? Remember that $x+y$ is measurable because is a continuous function. (Continuous functions have the property that the preimage of an open set is open, and the open sets are measurable and generate the borel sigma algebra, so continuous functions are measurable)

Comment: Yes,I got it.your help was very useful.Thanks again!

Comment: @Zeinab if you found the answer useful consider the possibility to accept it. It might help other people :).